# Which files get replaced when JDK is updated?

Tags: java

What I'd like to know is when I update my JDK from, say 1.6.0_19 to 1.6.0_20 for example, could you tell me exactly which files and/or folders belonging to the old version get replaced, or should I say overridden, by the folders/files in the new version. I'd like to store certain libraries downloaded from the web, preferably in the Java folder where the JDK and JRE are located without the risk of losing those files when I update.

If there is no concrete fashion of file replacement and retention then I would have no option but to direct Eclipse to a separate folder containing the mentioned JAR's.

Thank you.

Comment: Sun has been recommending for a long time, **not** to put 3rd party APIs into the Java directories.  Your 'last resort' is the correct strategy to pursue.  As to how you would make Eclipse understand that, I have no idea.

Answer (score 3):

The Java installer creates a new directory.  It doesn't overwrite the existing one.